# How do I get an OutputType value for my GeneXus pattern without conflicts with other extensions or patterns?

Tags: genexus

I'm developing a GeneXus pattern and I want it to have a reserved output.
For this I use

```
PackageManager.Manager.ReserveOutputTypeRange(EntityProviderBuildProcess.OUTPUT_ID_RWD, 1, CopyToTarget.IfDesign, true, BLPackageGuid.Patterns);
```

If the first parameter is repeated with another extension of the same GeneXus installation, only the first one will be able to be registered and the second one will give an error.
Is there any repository or place to register the integer value OutputType reserved numbers, to avoid collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enrique!

Take a look at https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43835,Reserved+OutputTypeId, but in short, talk to Armin.

Regards,